# How to prove $\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \leq 1$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

My analysis teacher uses this property quite often to prove limits and stuff and it is not so difficult to remember but how can you actually prove that

$\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq \frac{\sin(x)} x \leq 1$ ?

Comment: related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: Do you know taylor series for sine ?

Answer (score 5):

[image]
The area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)$.  The area of the colored wedge is $\frac{1}{2}x$, and the area of $\triangle ABD$ is $\frac{1}{2}\tan(x)$. 
 By inclusion, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\tan(x)\ge\frac{1}{2}x\ge\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)\tag{1}
$$
Dividing $(1)$ by $\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)$ and taking reciprocals, we get $$
\cos(x)\le\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le1\tag{2}
$$

when $$x \to o^+ \\ \sin x \leq x \leq \tan x \\$$ divide by $\sin x$
$$\frac{ \sin x}{\sin x} \leq \frac{  x}{\sin x} \leq \frac{ \tan x}{\sin x} \\ 
1 \leq \frac{  x}{\sin x} \leq \frac{ 1}{\cos x} \\\to 
\cos x \leq \frac{\sin x }{x} \leq 1$$ now :note that  $\cos x =\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$   so 
 $$x \to o^+ \to \sin x \leq x \\ 
 \sin^2 x \leq x^2 \\ 
-x^2 \leq -\sin^2 x \\
1-x^2 \leq 1-\sin^2 x \\
\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=\cos x \\ \to 
\\
\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq \cos x \leq \frac{\sin x }{x} \leq 1 $$

Comment: +1;It would be nice if you tell where did you get the first inequality,

Comment: And why you assume $x \to o^+$?

Comment: The first inequality is famous . It is part of squeeze theory .

Comment: I tried to make it clear .